# How do I insert a variable worksheet name into multiple excel formulas?

Tags: excel, variables

I'm trying to setup an excel sheet that will have a drop down box in a cell at the top which will contain different worksheet choices that are available from my workbook.  Once I choose a worksheet, I need this worksheet name to be referenced in many different excel formulas within this sheet.

Ex:

```
Choose an Application Group Filter:  *Drop Down Choices* Recap Filter
                                                         PB Filter
                                                         Membership Filter
```

Formula:

```
=COUNTIF('DropDownChoice'!AA:AA, 8)
```

I also want to have multiple worksheets that have this drop down box available at the top.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the INDIRECT() function

Example using your countif:

```
= COUNTIF( INDIRECT( CONCATENATE( dropdowncell, "!AA:AA") ,TRUE ), 8)
```

EDIT: Because you have space in your dropdown values you probably need

```
= COUNTIF( INDIRECT( CONCATENATE( "'", dropdowncell, "'!AA:AA") ,TRUE ), 8)
```